# How can I write a conditional split expression that separates row by string in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, conditional-statements

I am trying to filter the data in SSIS by a specific string. Any row that has"CSC" following the name in the column HOLDER_NAME needs to be discarded. I created a conditional split and inputted the expression `FINDSTRING("CSC", HOLDER_NAME, 1) > 0`. Yet nothing outputs to the specified second destination.

Comment: It doesn't go to error output, it goes to a second output with the name you give it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I do have it linked to a second output, I just chose a bad way to phrase it. It's edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your arguments backwards. The first argument to `FINDSTRING` is the string you are searching. The second argument is the text you are searching *for*.

Read the documentation next time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a `Lookup` transformation to search for your rule and only use the columns with 'No Match' to redirect where you want them to go

Comment: Thanks, I can use that for another problem I have.